# The BinarySearch Algorithm contains a Line I do not understand, can someone clarify it for me?

Tags: java, binary-search

```
public static int binarySearch(int[] numbers, int target) {
    int min = 0;
    int max = numbers.length – 1;

    while (min <= max) {
        int mid = (max + min) / 2;
        if (numbers[mid] == target) {
            return mid; // found it!
        } else if (numbers[mid] < target) {
            min = mid + 1; // too small
        } else {
            // numbers[mid] > target max = mid – 1; // too large
        }
    }

    // not found
    return –1;
}
```

Why reduce the array by 1?

Comment: What do you mean "why reduce the array by 1"?  The array isn't getting reduced.  And why would min get reduced, when it starts at 0?

Comment: The array isn't reduced by one, but the research scope gets smaller and smaller (divided by two) each time

Comment: Are you talking about `int max = numbers.length – 1;`? That's because if an array has a length of `1`, then the highest index is `0`. So you subtract `1`

Comment: Sorry, the numbers.length - 1, why do that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure what you're referring to when you mean "a line," so I'll just explain every line.

```
public static int binarySearch(int[] numbers, int target) {
int min = 0; //sets the starting search point for the binary search because array slots
//start at 0.

int max = numbers.length – 1; //sets the maximum length for the binary search.

while (min <= max) { //ensures that the binary search completes itself.
    int mid = (max + min) / 2; //every loop, binarySearch finds the exact middle
    if (numbers[mid] == target) { //if the middle number of the array is the target number....
        return mid; // found it! //returns the slot value where mid target was found
   else if (numbers[mid] < target) { //if the middle number is less than 
      //the target number
        min = mid + 1; // too small //value of the minimum is equal to the middle value
      //plus one. This will essentially cut the array "in half," making the sorting process
      //much quicker.
    } else {
        // numbers[mid] > target max = mid – 1; // too large //does the opposite of what 
    }
}

// not found
return –1; //no slot value found for the target number.
}
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: Oh, I see that people asked within the comments and explained it. Glad you found your solution.

Comment: Thank you very much Ben. That clarifies the whole solution. I'm currently learning how to code in order to build  a solution I want.